# Record voice from IPhone using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have been working on a mobile web application just for my own enjoyment and research. Everything seemed to be working pretty slick with HTML5/CSS and JavaScript for the client application, although it looks like I need a third party technology for voice recording. I had a pretty good solution working with Flash, but after testing it with my IPhone, I had remembered that they don't seem to support flash which is disappointing because I had a pretty good solution going. I want to record voice using HTML5  in Iphone  and android. Is there any way?

Answer (score 28):

You could try HTML Media Capture. An [article on dev.opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/media-capture-in-mobile-browsers/) says:

> Android OS 3.0 was the first platform to provide HTML Media Capture
>   support, via its default Android Webkit browser. Now HTML Media
>   Capture is also supported by:
>
> - Safari and Chrome Mobile for iOS 6+
> - Chrome Mobile for Android OS 3+
> - Firefox Mobile for Android OS 3+
> - Opera 16 for Android OS 3+
>
> Nonetheless some of them only partially implement the specification or
>   implement an older W3C specification, that makes the code above
>   slightly different:
>
> ```
> <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
> <input type="file" accept="video/*" capture="camcorder">
> <input type="file" accept="audio/*" capture="microphone">
> ```

It links out to [a demo page](http://dev.opera.com/articles/media-capture-in-mobile-browsers/demo/) which you could try on your mobile. I also found [this example page](http://anssiko.github.io/html-media-capture/). In my quick iOS 7 testing though, it only worked correctly for photos and videos.

---

*Edit*: [Further reading](http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/09/new-html-tricks-for-web-developers-in-apples-ios-6-2/) suggests `accept="audio/*"` isn't actually supported on iOS 6 and 7, only `accept="image/*"` and `accept="video/*"`.

---

*Update*: A quick test on iOS 8.3 suggests nothing has changed here: `accept="image/*"` and `accept="video/*"` are supported, but `accept="audio/*"` is not.

---

*Update*: A quick test on iOS 10.0.2 suggests `accept="audio/*"` is still not supported, although it looks like you might be able to upload an audio file from iCloud Drive or Dropbox now.

---

*Update*: Despite what it says in [the Webkit blog post](https://webkit.org/blog/7477/new-web-features-in-safari-10-1/), there still seems to be no support for `accept="audio/*"` in iOS 10.3 on my iPhone 5S.

---

*Update*: Same story in iOS 11.0.3. There still seems to be no support for `accept="audio/*"` on my iPhone 5S.

---

*Update*: Still the same in iOS 12.4.3. There seems to be no support for `accept="audio/*"` on my iPhone 5S.

Comment: Photo and Video capture is not a big deal. I am having problem recording only audio using HTML5.

Comment: How can I get sound recorder option as this option is coming here. http://dev.opera.com/articles/media-capture-in-mobile-browsers/

Comment: @BilalAhmed According to http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/09/new-html-tricks-for-web-developers-in-apples-ios-6-2/ it only supports `video` and `image` and that doesn't seem to have changed in iOS7 :-( The best workaround I can think of is to have the user record a video, upload, then use server-side processing to pull the audio out of it?

Answer (score 2):

**This will not work on a website**, but if you want to rework your web-app into a mobile app using Cordova this will let you use the microphone input. Takes some knowledge of web audio api to get working.

https://github.com/edimuj/cordova-plugin-audioinput

And RecorderJS to record its output:

https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Someone above mentioned RecorderJS not working on mobile but it does, it's just the mic input that doesn't work.

There is not currently any way I'm aware of to record mic input in a browser on mobile

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTML5 [WebAudio API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/).

Introduction to audio and video [capturing Capture audio & video in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Nice Library to record audio with samples [Recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs)

Comment: Working sample link is not opening.

Comment: try this Recorder.js link it's simple

Comment: Recorder.js works fine in computer, but not on mobile.

Comment: The question ask for IPHONE,  this is not supported in IOS

Answer (score -2):

On webkit-browsers i.e.Chrome and Safari in iOS you can use the get user media api with `webkitGetUserMedia`.
Details can be found here :
[html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/#toc-webaudio-api)

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/stream it's not yet supported on iOS Safari. You might be able to use HTML media capture though, mentioned earlier in the same article: `<input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone">`. (Additional nitpick: Chrome and Opera no longer use Webkit - they forked a while back and now use Blink.)

Comment: Thanks for the latest info @OllyHodgson ... :)

Comment: Do you have any complete working solution? I have tried many but they work only on computer, not on mobile.

Comment: As the comment above, it seems this is still not supported on mobile... This is a complete working demo, though for reference: http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

Comment: This link is working fine on computer but still not in mobile. I have a question that how microphone access works in www.google.com (for voice base search) in mobile browser?

Comment: I know for sure that in Chrome for android you have to turn it on using chrome://flags

Comment: which option to enable in flags?