# How to record audio in browser on iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, audio, getusermedia

All tutorials I found make use of `getUserMedia()`, which doesn't exist in iOS Browsers. Is there any other way to record Audio in the Browser on iOS?

Comment: Short answer is no, for more discussion see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287112/record-voice-from-iphone-using-html5

Comment: @DanLynch iOS does support getUserMedia since iOS11. Please see my answer.

Comment: @DanLynch the acccepted answer works, since September 2017. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS 11, `getUserMedia` **is** supported in iOS browsers.

You can use this simple example:

```
constraints = { audio: true, video: true };
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(handleSuccess);

var handleSuccess = function (stream) {  

    var context = new AudioContext();
    var processor = context.createScriptProcessor(1024, 1, 1);
    var input = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    processor.connect(context.destination);
    input.connect(processor);

    processor.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
        // Get sound packets from microphone            
        // e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0) will now have sound packets
    };
};
```